# Use globally installed @angular/core instead of local

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm

So I have `@angular/core` module installed as a global NPM dependency. I want all my Angular projects to use that version.

Unfortunately, it seems like Angular doesn't like it. Every time I run `npm start` in my project root, this is the error I got:

```
[user@host]$ npm start
...
ERROR in Could not resolve module @angular/core
```

I've googled the error in many ways and found that maybe the `tsconfig.json` file is corrupted in some way. So I've changed the `baseUrl` to the `npm root -g` directory, but then, another error has come up:

```
[user@host]$ npm start
...
ERROR in No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'
```

What's even more interesting is that when I run `ng version` I can see strange `Angular: undefined` entry:

```
$ ng version

Angular CLI: 7.3.9
Node: 10.16.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: undefined
... 

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.13.9 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         7.3.9 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   7.3.9 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          7.3.9 (cli-only)
@schematics/update           0.13.9 (cli-only)
```

So as you can see there's no `@angular/core` entry neither. Which is odd because e.x. `@angular-devkit/core` is also installed globally, so why on Earth the `@angular/core` is not recognized? When I install Angular locally then everything works fine.

Comment: 1. That doesn't seem odd, the `@angular-devkit/` packages are dependencies for the CLI, not necessarily for your local project, whereas the `@angular/` dependencies are project-based. 2. Why do we have to *assume* you can't do anything else; can you provide the actual context?

Comment: 2. Is it better now? I just wanted to avoid answers which would not answer my question. The truth is that I actually do not have other choice and have to install @angular/core globally but I'm struggling to get it working

Comment: *Why* do you have no other choice, though? If we understand the context, we can help you find better solutions.

Comment: Okay, maybe I should have said that **I think** I have no other choice, sorry for the misunderstanding. The case is that I want to run multiple Angular projects simultaneously. All projects will use the same Angular version so in order to save disk space I want to have common modules installed globally. One of the modules is `@angular/core` but I can't start any of the projects unless I install it locally per project (which I really don't want to do)

Comment: Are you really that constrained? Storage these days is cheaper than the time you've spent writing this!

Comment: That's totally the answer I wanted to avoid ;) I just want it to work the way I've described it. If that's possible - please advice how can I do it? If that's impossible - it's ok, just tell me why and I'll accept that. Simple as that ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have solved it by "cheating". I have taken advantage of the fact that I use Linux OS and created a symlink to the global node_modules folder and now Angular thinks everything is in place:

```
$ ln -s /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules node_modules
```